# Which router firmware supports external drives, FTP, VPN, and BitTorrent?

Tags: networking, router, ftp, dd-wrt, tomato

I have a Linksys WRT54GL Router.  I'm open to getting another router if it won't suit my needs.

Which firmware should I install?
Which version/build of the firmware?
Any additional modifications I should make to the firmware?

Requirements:

1. **Connect an external hard drive** to the router, so that any devices connected to the router can access files from the hard drive.
2. **Run an FTP server** (with SSH) on the router, so files on the external hard-drive can be accessed from anywhere.
3. **Run VPN**, so that certain computers can access the hard drives over VPN.
4. **Run a BitTorrent client** on the router with the files stored on the external hard drive.

Answer (score 3):

I believe all that is possible using OpenWRT.

USB Storage: http://patinya-tuk.blogspot.com/2009/09/usb-storage-howtoopenwrt.html

NAS: http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/nfs.server

VPN: https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=1800

BitTorrent: http://bredsaal.dk/transmission-bittorrent-client-on-openwrt

I'd like to add this won't be easy. You are asking a router, any router, to do things it was not designed to do. You are much better off creating a proper server and forwarding the ports as needed.

Comment: It would be great if you could back up your claim a bit (e.g. related links from the OpenWRT project, how-to's, etc.).

Comment: @slhck - Thanks for editing for formatting, I see how you did it and will do it myself in future.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!!!  I will give it a try and update you all with the results.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use ClearOS if you have an old PC in your closet.  ClearOS is designed as a small business server/router, so it can do all the things you want.