# Can't store Youtube videos directly to my FTP home server

Tags: router, ftp, download, bittorrent, youtube

I have a TP-Link TD-W8968 ADSL router modem, which supports FTP server application by hooking a USB mass storage device on it.

Previously I was downloading all my .torrent files to my computer, but now I started downloading it to the FTP server application on this TP-Link router using uTorrent. In this process I do not have to keep my computer powered on for all the time when the torrents are getting downloaded to the router based FTP application, as the torrent file gets downloaded straight to router connected USB after pointing the torrent downloads to the FTP USB storage on the router. The computer can be turned off while downloading, it does not affect the torrent download.

The problem is while I am trying to download Youtube videos with IDM (Internet Download Manager) and point them to the USB running on router FTP server application (like the process I use for uTorrent download specified above), the download stops when I shut down the computer, unlike uTorrent downloads which keep on downloading to USB without the need of my computer to be powered on all the time.

Is there any way I can download Youtube videos with IDM straight to TP-Link FTP server USB, without letting my computer be powered on for the entire download?

Why isn't IDM downloading straight away To USB like uTorrent is downloading without the need of a computer?

Comment: Run youtube-dl.  https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl

Comment: Please clarify your question, maintaining **only** the most important points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I've formatted and fixed your text I can give you an answer, although it isn't what you wanted to hear, and it doesn't have any reliable sources:

## Short story:

IDM isn't going to work because it runs **only** on Windows.

## Slightly larger story:

The router has hardware inside it that supports keeping torrent connections alive.

## The full story:

It seemed odd that you were being able to use uTorrent while your PC was turned off. From a computer science perspective, you **always** need a PC on (and not sleeping or hibernating) to allow processes running, sending and receiving signals.

However, I remembered **some** newer routers have an integrated torrent client within them that can rout their signal to a FTP connected drive. So, they can run **independently** of a PC as long as they have an external drive coupled to it.

The router you described is the one in this [TP-Link page](http://www.tp-link.us/products/details/?categoryid=&model=TD-W8968#down). However, I don't see any clear reference to there existing a torrent client in the hardware or firmware. Either it is hidden or you (or someone else) installed a hacked firmware that enabled a torrent client to work.

For sourcing issues, I have [this](http://wl500g.info/archive/index.php/t-7643.html) that describes how to use a router as a torrent client, but it isn't the same model as you described. It shows it is possible, just that. Upon another search I came across this SuperUser post: [Which router firmware supports external drives, FTP, VPN, and BitTorrent?](https://superuser.com/q/335598/228536)

[IDM](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/download.html) is a Windows application. This being said, it will **only** run on Windows. Since Windows is installed **only** in your computer (the router has a "special OS") you need it on to download your Youtube videos.

Unless someone somewhere has developed a firmware *for your router* with that capability, the best course of action I recall is to ask a webpage to do the download for you then send it to the FTP, like a proxy (which is a good assumption, since you already told us about your drive serving as a FTP server).

UPDATE: Skimming through @Zoredache link I see that it, coupled with a Linux firmware in the router, *might* work. But I don't see anything on the documentation or the FAQ that suggests it works. It's a try-and-see situation.

Comment: Firmware on the router is not hacked i downloaded the firmware update from official TP-link website. I used hit & trial method which worked for torrent downloads. You-tube videos can be downloaded running a PHP script on a FTP server, but the process to download multiple videos with desired video quality as hosted on youtube 240p, 360p, 480p etc with a PHP script every time doesn't make sense, Can you elaborate more on your suggestion "to ask a webpage to do the download for you". Thanks a lot for your help, i appreciate your generosity

Comment: Take for instance [this](http://www.clipconverter.cc/) site. You just paste the Youtube address and the site does most of the work for you. You can also setup your browser to send all downloads to the FTP drive, so, in theory, it should work. At any rate, I believe this answered your main question.

Comment: practically not working :(, finally decided to buy a new windows 7 based mini tablet, as of right now i think IDM is best suited for my needs, because it has pause and resume download functionality which i definitely need, anyways you were a great help, voting you up Doktoro Reichard.